# Access 2002 - display customer address on form text field

Tags: ms-access

I want to display the address of a customer (contact in my database) on a form that displays other basic information about customers.  The address comes from an address table keyed on contact_id.  I have tried a number of ways - `=trim(address!address_line_1)` in the field's control source is one such.

Another failed attempt: `= [address]![address_line_1] where  [address]![contact_id] = [forms!contacts1!contact_id]`. This one caused a `#Name?` error.

I am also unsure how to relate the control source query to the selected contact_id.

Any thoughts on how to display address details on a form showing other basic contact details for a particular customer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do --

Surround the dbField name with quotes   "[address_line_1]"

Surround the tblName with quotes        "[address]"

Surround ContactID with quotes          "[contact_id]= '"

If ContactID is a string, then add a preceeding & trailing single-quote
If ContactID is numeric, remove the single-quotes from example

```
=DLookUp("[address_line_1]","[address]", _
"[contact_id]= '" & [Forms]![contacts1]![contact_id] & "'")
```

Comment: Yes - that did it. Thank you! Wow - it's not very intuitive. I don't usually use Access, but had to for this job. Looks like a lot more of the learning curve to come!